# how to update mySql table by supplying primary key?

Tags: java, mysql

I have a MySQL database. One of the tabels is this:

```
sqlString = "CREATE TABLE Parents ("
            + "ChildID SMALLINT NOT NULL,"
            + "Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,"
            + "Address VARCHAR(100),"
            + "MobilePhone LONG,"
            + "WorkPhone LONG,"
            + "PRIMARY KEY (ChildID, Name),"
            + "FOREIGN KEY(ChildID) REFERENCES Children(ChildID))";
stmt.executeUpdate(sqlString);
```

I execute this update first:
`sqlString = "INSERT INTO Parents (ChildID, Name) VALUES (1, 'Mom')";`

it works fine. But when I need to add more information to a parent, I just get an unexplained SQLSyntaxError from this:

`sqlString = "UPDATE Parents SET Address='Fakestreet 1'WHERE ChildID=1 AND Name='Mom'";`

it works perfect if I remove the AND condition. I have exhausted every possibility I can think of to fix it.

Why am I getting a syntax error?

I'm guessing the problem is that the 2 columns in my WHERE clause is the primary key of Parents. Am I supposed to use foreign keys somehow to add information on a child's parents? Is there a practical use of declaring practical keys at all? The way I'm seeing it the only use is internally for the DBMS.

Comment: is it a wrongly formatted question or did you forgot the space before AND in UPDATE Parents SET Address='Fakestreet 1'WHERE ChildID=1 AND Name='Mom'

Comment: It's not wrongly formatted. Spacing is irelevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give space before AND in where clause "ChildID=1AND"

Comment: That would go in the category of 'possibilities I could think of to fix it' ^^

Comment: Ok so amidst all the syntax changes I tried making, including spacing where u indicated, I hadn't noticed the error I got changed to a wrong column name. Unless surrounded by apostrophe `WHERE ChildID='1'AND` like this, spacing is needed for both WHERE and AND. Which is why the query worked with only the the first part of my WHERE clause.